# Text going over footer

Tags: html, css, web

I have a little problem on my site, the text from the content div is going over the footer.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
test
</div>
<div class="footer">
<font size="2px">
  <p>text</p>
  <hr color="red">
  <p>text2</p>
  <p>tex3</p>
  <p>E-mail: <a href="mailto:text4?" target="_top">text4</a>; <a href="mailto:text5?" target="_top">text5</a>; <a href="mailto:text6?" target="_top">text6</a></p>
  <p><a href="website">website</a></p>
  </font>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
padding-top : 121px;
position: absolute;
width : 100%;
display:inline-block;
}
.footer {
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

If I write a lot of text, with `<br/>` included, it goes over the footer. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: why `position:absolute` ....?

Comment: Should I change it to fixed?

Comment: you will need to set a z-index for the footer that is higher than the content but I wouldn't use absolute positioning - there are many better ways to do a sticky footer

Comment: can you remove the position: absolute; display: inline-block; from both i think it should fix the issue

Comment: @andrewsaeed, thanks, lol, I'm so stupid sometimes